# How to set default ctags options in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

in gvim on the toolbar there is a button to execute ctags command which generates tags for current directory, unfortunately the default option is **-R** only.

I want to customize the command and add few additional options when clicking on the button, I've been reading trough documentation but didn't manage to figure out on how to do it..

I know one can map a key (which I did) but I want to make the same for that button.
how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd skip Vim entirely for this, and [configure ctags via your `~/.ctags` file](http://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags#toc_6). That way, your options will be preserved no matter how you run ctags. You could also [change the command for that button](https://superuser.com/questions/11289/how-do-i-customize-the-gvim-toolbar) instead, if you only wanted it to affect gvim.

Comment: first option works for command line only, but the second one actually did the trick :D Thanks you so much!